# import data from access to relational database (oracle)

Tags: oracle, ms-access, rdbms

Is it possible to transfer data from non-relational databases to relational database systems? I have data in an access database and I want to export it to a relation oracle database. If possible, how do i set up the relations between various tables? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Oracle with MS-Access.

- Step 1: Prepare the MS-Access environment
- Step 2: Define ODBC connectivity
- Step 3: Prepare the Oracle Environment
- Step 4: Configure and Start the Oracle Listener
- Step 5: Configure Oracle HS:
- Step 6: Configure Oracle connectivity to Windows Machine
- Step 7: Create a database link

This article shows how Oracle's Heterogeneous Services can be configured to allow a database to connect to a Microsoft Access database using standard databases links.

http://www.orafaq.com/node/60

2. To migrate a Microsoft Access Database to Oracle Database 11g read the following link

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm